# Windows Active Directory and Linux integration: new AD Group does not show up in Linux

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba, user-management

In my organization, the support team has created a new AD group for me but it does not show up on any of the nodes in our cluster(using RHEL).

I went through [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.12.linux.aspx) to understand Windows and Linux integration and looks like we are using the 'RID mapping'. (Which means an user group created on AD should be ready to be used on Linux.) This I confirmed by looking at following /etc/samba/smb.conf :

```
security = ads 
idmap config * : backend = rid
```

The person who created the AD group has provided screenshots of Active Directory Wizard to show the group exists. But I am stuck with not seeing it when I 'getent group group_name' for it.

Can anyone direct me to what else I might investigate?